Concurreny DbContext / Hot Chocolate ASP.NET Core Web API project
I'm working on integrating a GraphQL API into my ASP.NET Core project using Hot Chocolate packages. I'm encountering an issue where I receive the error message:

A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext

This error occurs when I make requests that involve both of my entities. However, when I query them separately, everything works fine.
These are my entities:
namespace Todo.Data.Entities
{
    public class Person 
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public List<Entry>? EntryInfo { get; set; }
        //virtual eklenmedi. 
    }

    public class Entry
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Person))]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person? PersonInfo { get; set; }
    }
}

Object type classes:
namespace Todo.GraphQLModels.Types
{
    public class PersonType : ObjectType<Person>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Person> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Id)
                .Type<NonNullType<IntType>>(); 

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Name)
                .Type<StringType>();

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Surname)
                .Type<StringType>();

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.EntryInfo)
                .Type<ListType<EntryType>>();
        }
    }

    public class EntryType : ObjectType<Entry>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Entry> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Id)
                .Type<NonNullType<IntType>>(); 

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Title)
                .Type<StringType>();

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Content)
                .Type<StringType>();

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Date)
                .Type<DateTimeType>();

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.PersonInfo)
                .Type<PersonType>();
        }
    }
}

My services:
namespace Todo.Business.Services
{
    public interface IPersonService
    {
        Task<List<Person>> GetAllPeople();
    }

    public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {
        private readonly TodoDbContext _dbContext;

        public PersonService(TodoDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPeople()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Persons.Include(x => x.EntryInfo)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public interface IEntryService
    {
        Task<List<Entry>> GetAllEntries();
    }

    public class EntryService : IEntryService
    {
        private readonly TodoDbContext _dbContext;

        public EntryService(TodoDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<Entry>> GetAllEntries()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Entries.Include(x=>x.PersonInfo)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}

Query class
namespace Todo.GraphQLModels.Queries
{
    public class Query
    {
        private readonly IPersonService _personService;
        private readonly IEntryService _entryService;

        public Query(IPersonService personService, IEntryService entryService)
        {
            _personService = personService;
            _entryService = entryService;
        }

        public Task<List<Person>> GetPeople() => _personService.GetAllPeople();

        public Task<List<Entry>> GetEntries() => _entryService.GetAllEntries();
    }
}

Query type class
namespace Todo.GraphQLModels.Queries
{
    public class QueryType : ObjectType<Query>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Query> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor
           .Field(f => f.GetPeople())
           .Type<ListType<PersonType>>()
           .Resolve(ctx => ctx.Service<IPersonService>().GetAllPeople());

            descriptor
                .Field(f => f.GetEntries())
                .Type<ListType<EntryType>>()
                .Resolve(ctx => ctx.Service<IEntryService>().GetAllEntries());
        }
    }
}

My DbContext class:
namespace Todo.Data
{
    public class TodoDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public TodoDbContext(DbContextOptions<TodoDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasData(
                    new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "a", Surname = "a"},
                    new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "b", Surname = "b"},
                    new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "c", Surname = "c" }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
            .HasData(
                    new Entry() { Id = 1, Content = "test1content", Title = "test1", PersonId=1 },
                    new Entry() { Id = 2, Content = "test2content", Title = "test2", PersonId=2 }
                );
        }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }
}

And my configuration in program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPersonService, PersonService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEntryService, EntryService>();

builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddType<PersonType>()
    .AddType<EntryType>()
    .AddQueryType<QueryType>();


builder.Services.AddCors(x =>
{
    x.AddPolicy("def", x =>
    {
        x.AllowAnyMethod();
        x.AllowAnyHeader();
        x.AllowAnyOrigin();

    });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseGraphQLPlayground().MapGraphQL("/graphql", "graph");
}

app.MapGraphQL("/graphql");
app.UseCors("def");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

